# Unique files mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, mongoose

I need to have unique files mongodb, I am using mongoose, and my code is well

```
mySchema.method({
    putFile : function (data, cb) {
        var item = this;
        async.waterfall([
            function (callback) {
                exif.metadata(data, callback);
            },
            function (mts, callback){
                var metas = {};
                for (var i in mts) metas[i] = mts[i];
                //Find a md5
                var gri = new GridStore(f, item._id.toString(), undefined, 'w', { 
                    metadata: metas,
                    content_type: mts.mimeType
                });
                gri.open(callback);
            },

            function (file, callback){
                file.write( data, true, callback);
            }
        ], function (err, result) {
            if(err) return cb(err);
            item.file.id = result.fileId;
            item.file.contentType = result.contentType;
            cb(err, item);
        });
    }
});
```

Is that the files in mongodb has a hash in md5, which is constructed with the metadata. Do not know how to do this md5, and generate a search to see if the file exists. As the md5 hash is constructed as the search is done?

Comment: I don't really understand your question...do you want a unique index on the md5 so you can't insert another file with the same md5 value?

Comment: Exactly, I want to be unique MD5 for each file.